# Excluding in-store data from query in Apollo.js

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, react-apollo

I am currently introducing Apollo in a project and I have some doubts about caching / gql components composition.

I'll explain using an example: Say we have a `<Widget>` component "hoced" with gql query defining it's data requirements, which is quite a long list. This component doesn't have `<ApolloProvider>`, because it isn't meant to be used standalone - it has to be rendered in some other component using `<ApolloProvider>`. Then I have two apps, using this component: `<SimpleApp>` and `<ComplexApp>`. When `<SimpleApp>` renders `<Widget>`, the latter just downloads the data and all is fine. `<ComplexApp>` however, already has part of the data used by `<Widget>`. I'd like `<Widget>` to figure that out and download only the lacking data, not the whole set defined in it's query. The business logic here would be sort of checking the Apollo's store for what is already there and remove those fields from the `<Widget>`'s query.

The queries are in form of:

```
 query WidgetQuery {
   someType {
     id
     a
     b
     c
     d
   }
 }

 query ComplexAppQuery {
   someType {
     b
     c
   }
 }
```

So when `<Widget>` is inside `<ComplexApp>`, I wouldn't like it to download "a" and "d", but otherwise yes.

Is there any way I can achieve this, are custom resolvers the proper way to go?

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this using the `@skip` and `@include` directives based on a prop of the `<Widget>` component that is passed from its parent `<SimpleApp>` or `<ComplexApp>` component. Let's call the prop `all`:

```
<SimpleApp>
  <Widget all={true}/>
</SimpleApp>
<ComplexApp>
  <Widget all={false}>
</ComplexApp>
```

As Apollo Client typically uses `id` and `__typename` (automatically added to each query) to identify nodes, you would need to include `id` as well. So the Query would look like this:

```
query widgetQuery($all: Boolean!) {
  someType {
    id
    a @include(if: $all)
    b
    c
    d @include(if: $all)
  }
}
```

`a` and `d` are only included if the passed `$all` variable is `true`.

In Apollo, you can pass props to variables by passing a function taking one argument to the `options` of the query:

```
const widgetQuery = gql`
  query widgetQuery($all: Boolean!) {
    someType {
      id
      a @include(if: $all)
      b
      c
      d @include(if: $all)      
    }
  }
`

const WidgetWithQuery = graphql(widgetQuery, {
  options: (ownProps) => ({
    variables: {
      all: ownProps.all
    }
  })
})(Widget)
```

Now, Apollo Client makes sure to combine all obtained fields from `SimpleApp` and `ComplexApp` for a given node based on `id`.

For more information check [this interactive tutorial](https://www.graph.cool/docs/faq/how-to-use-graphql-directives-moach1gich/) about `@skip` and `@include`.

Comment: At first it seemed to be a good solution, but after second thought it doesn't work without further hassle - if I run the query with `all = false` (so when I know that `a` and `b` are already in the store) I still don't get it in `<Widget>` - Apollo doesn't pass to the component the fields that are excluded with a directive. So unfortunately, this isn't useful in this case. Beside, there's still necessity to manually check whether `a` and `b` are in the store and unfortunately there's rarely a luxury of knowing that at build time.

Comment: The only solution I see for now is adding some proxy element using `read(Query|Fragment)` to: a). check the store for data existence in the store and set/unset `all` variable; b). if only partial query is sent (so `all=false`), reading from the store the the fields that were excluded from the query and appending them to Apollo's `data`. I'm afraid this solution would be really slow, have to check it though.

Comment: ...or just split the query into two queries. The simplest solution, but lacks versatility, makes code harder to read, depends on batching (`<Widget>` has depends on two queries, so both have to be fired when rendering), fires multiple redux actions at once... Not really nice either.